# How to know from aws-php-sdk if an Object inside my S3 bucket is visible to everyone (is set as public)?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I own a S3 bucket, which has two objects inside:

**testPublic.jpg** , which is public (everyone, given the URL, can access it)

**testNotPublic.jpg** , which is not set as public.

I need a method that can tell me if the file in question is visible by everyone.

From S3, I can execute the following:

```
dd($s3->getObject([
    'Bucket' => $bucketName,
    'Key'    => $filekey,

]));
```

Which returns information about the object, but nothing about its permissions.

I can also execute the following:

```
dd($s3->getObjectAcl([
        'Bucket' => $bucketName,
        'Key'    => $filekey,

    ]));
```

Which returns information about the permissions, something like

```
object(Aws\Result)[1125]
  private 'data' => 
    array (size=4)
      'RequestCharged' => string '' (length=0)
      'Owner' => 
        array (size=1)
          'ID' => string 'ca299b95fREDACTED129f7' (length=64)
      'Grants' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      '@metadata' => 
        array (size=4)
          'statusCode' => int 200
          'effectiveUri' => string 'https://s3.us-REDACTED-2.amazonaws.com/REDACTED/test.jpg?acl' (length=73)
          'headers' => 
            array (size=6)
              ...
          'transferStats' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
```

Which inside the key `Grants` has something like

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'Grantee' => 
        array (size=1)
          'ID' => string 'ca2REDACTEDf7' (length=64)
      'Permission' => string 'FULL_CONTROL' (length=12)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'Grantee' => 
        array (size=1)
          'URI' => string 'http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers' (length=47)
      'Permission' => string 'READ' (length=4)
```

This last item only visible if the file is public.

So far I haven't found an implemented method that could allow me to pass it the `$filekey` and return if this file is visible by everyone.

The only way I see I could do it is to implement it myself, looking at the result of `getObjectAcl()` and performing a search for the element that has  `http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers` with permision `READ`

¿Is there a better way I am missing?

Comment: I think there is not better solution in this case because AWS only support get ACL of `an object`. So if you want to public, just create S3 bucket and set public for hole bucket. Seperate private/public bucket is the best.

Comment: Why don't you create a separate bucket one to serve private content and one to server public content , why complicate things this way ?